# Hyper-V Replica Capacity Planner stuck getting VM information

Tags: hyper-v, replication, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to use the [Capacity Planner for Hyper-V Replica](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=39057) tool to estimate requirements for a replica site.

It keeps getting stuck "Getting the VM and VHD from primary site, this can take upto several minutes...".  I've waited over an hour, and it still sits there.

The primary site is a 3 node Hyper-V 2012R2 cluster.  I have installed and configured the Hyper-V Replication Broker role on the cluster.  For now, it's set to use HTTP without any certificates.

I don't have a replica site yet, so I've selected "Skip tests involving Replica site".  For the primary site, I've tried pointing it at both the replication broker, and at one of the individual nodes.  It gets stuck in the same place.

EDIT:  I now have a host to use as a temporary replica site, and tried it with that.  No change, it still gets stuck in the same place.

Other things I've tried:

- Disabled windows firewall on all 3 nodes
- Running the tool from one of the nodes, logged in as a domain admin account
- Moving all the VMs off of one node, and pointing the tool at that now empty node
- Let it run for longer - left it alone overnight.
- Downloaded the tool again in case it was corrupt
- Rebooted my computer
- Per @Signal15's suggestion, checked port 135 is open - it is (tested the powershell way, from my desktop to all 3 nodes + the cluster IP)
- Per @Brian's suggestion, checked remote WMI is working - it is, I can use the Get-WMIObject command in powershell remotely against all 3 nodes.
- Rebooted all 3 nodes

In all cases, it gets stuck at the exact same spot.

Any idea how to figure out why it is freezing?  Have I missed configuring something important for the tool to run?

Comment: From the docx included page 10: "3. Remote-WMI is used to enumerate the virtual machines on the primary server:".

Comment: Curious if Port 135 is accessible on the remote-machines...check via Powershell here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566052/how-to-check-network-port-access-and-display-useful-message

Comment: @Brian tested remote WMI - it is working properly

Comment: @Signal15 Port 135 is accessible on all 3 nodes.